# How to test a resolve route in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, selenium, karma-runner

I'm trying to test a simple component that is subscribed to a router event and I don't know how to mock that part of the code. The error is the following: Cannot read property 'pairwise' of undefined.

> Cannot read property 'pairwise' of undefined

This is my test:

```
describe('AppComponent', function () {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
    var tendersServiceStub = {};
    var scrollServiceStub = {};
    var routerStub = {};

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AppComponent],
            providers: [
                {provide: TendersService, useValue: tendersServiceStub},
                {provide: ScrollService, useValue: scrollServiceStub},
                {provide: Router, useValue: routerStub}
            ],
            imports: [RouterTestingModule],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents().then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
            fixture.detectChanges()
        });
    }));

    it('should instantiate component', () => {
        // console.log(fixture); UNDEFINED
    });
});
```

And this is the component:

```
export class AppComponent {
    appTitle: string = 'Magic';

    constructor(private router: Router, private tendersService: TendersService, private scrollService: ScrollService) {
        this.router.events.pairwise().subscribe((e) => {
            if ((e[0] instanceof NavigationEnd) && (e[1] instanceof NavigationStart)) {
                this.resetSearchCache(e);
            }
        })
    }

    private resetSearchCache(e: any) {
        if ((e[1].url == '/home') || (e[1].url == '/advancedSearch')) {
            if (!e[0].url.includes('/detail')) {
                //DO SOMETHING
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The router you "stubbed" is an empty object and so you haven't got the properties events and pairwise

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the `events` property and make the value an `Observable` that emits the events array.

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

let mockRouter = {
                          // see notes below. this may be incorrect
  events: Observable.of([ new NavigationStart(1, '/'),
                          new NavigationEnd(1, '/', '/home')])
};
```

See also docs for [`NavigationEnd`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationEnd-class.html), [`NavigationStart`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationStart-class.html), and [`RoutesRecognized`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RoutesRecognized-class.html). From what I tested, the array actually consists of `[NavigationStart, RoutesRecognized]` on a start event, and `[RoutesRecognized, NavigationEnd]` on an end event. So your logic may not be correct.

The other option is to just use the real routing. Sometimes this can be beneficial, and it's not really that hard to set up. For example in your case, you can just add a dummy component to the test that the `home` route goes to. Then configure the routes with `RouterTestingModule.withRoutes`

```
@Component({
  template: `
  `
})
class HomeComponent {}

describe('WelcomeComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let component: AppComponent;
  let router: Router;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
      ])],
      declarations: [ AppComponent, HomeComponent ],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    router.initialNavigation();
  });
});
```

With this, the first route event will get triggered. Also if you want, you could also trigger other events manually with the `Router` by navigating somewhere else.